# Why does this shared buffer work?

Tags: c#, object-oriented

**Background**

The following code snippet is taken from a problem in, *Visual C# 2005: How to Program, by Paul and Harvey Deitel* (pp. 735). The code snippet is more or less an application for accessing data using 2 threads via a buffer (called `shared`). Just skip the code snippet, and look below if you would like a brief description of what is going on (before reading my question).

```
// Fig. 15.8: UnsynchronizedBufferTest.cs
// Showing multiple threads modifying a shared object without
// synchronization.
using System;
using System.Threading;

class UnsynchronizedBufferTest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create shared object used by threads
        UnsynchronizedBufferTest shared = new UnsynchronizedBuffer();

        // Random object used by each thread
        Random random = new Random();

        // create Producer and Consumer objects 
        Producer producer = new Producer(shared, random);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(shared, random);

        // create threads for producer and consumer and set
        // delegates for each thread
        Thread producerThread =
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(producer.Produce));
        producerThread.Name = "Producer";

        Thread consumerThread =
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(consumer.Consume));
        consumerThread.Name = "Consumer";

        // start each thread
        producerThread.Start();
        consumerThread.Start();
    } // end Main
} // end class UnsynchronizedBufferTest
```

Just for the basic idea of what is going on here, a producer thread is running that *puts* data into a buffer (called `shared`). Also, a consumer thread is running that *gets* the data from the buffer.

The `Producer` and `Consumer` objects are somehow sharing this buffer, which is what I am having trouble understanding. From what I have always understood about the C# language, when an object is passed to a method, it is only a *copy* or *instance* that actually gets passed. I guess that must be wrong, because when the `Producer` puts the data in the buffer, the `Consumer` sees it...

The code snippet for the buffer (in case anyone needs that) is as follows (pp. 734). Honestly I don't think it will have anything to do with the answer, and that the answer has more to do with the C# language because really all this class represents is an integer.

```
// Fig. 15.7: UnsynchronizedBuffer.cs
// An unsynchronized shared buffer implementation.
using System;
using System.Threading;

// this class represents a single shared int
public class UnsynchronizedBuffer : Buffer
{
    // buffer shared by producer and consumer threads
    private int buffer = -1;

    // property buffer
    public int Buffer
    {
        get
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} reads {1}",
                Thread.CurrentThread.Name, buffer);
            return buffer;
        } // end get
        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} writes {1}",
                Thread.CurrentThread.Name, value);
            buffer = value;
        } // end set
    } // end property Buffer
} // end class UnsynchronizedBuffer
```

**Question**

How is it that both objects (the `Producer` and the `Consumer`) are able to see the changes that each other makes? (i.e. when the `Producer` sets the data, the `Consumer` can see the new data)

I must be missing something in my fundamental understanding of C#.

Comment: C# (and Java) do not copy object types when passing parameters, only the object reference is copied.  However, if they did, they wouldn't make a deep copy in any case.  To prevent sharing in this example, not only would a copy of the objects (Producer/Consumer) be required but a *deep copy* at that (of course, the language does neither shallow nor deep copying here).  FWIW, local variable assignment works the same as parameter passing, i.e. two local variables can refer to the same object, whether they are in the same method or not...

Comment: Hopefully what follows in the book is how shared objects are manipulated by multiple threads with synchronization.

Comment: @dbasnett Yeah... **15.7 Producer/Consumer Relationship with Thread Synchronization** :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From what I have always understood about the C# language, when an object is passed to a method, it is only a copy or instance that actually gets passed.

That's where you are getting mixed up.

All variables in C# are references to objects. The buffer object in your example lives on the heap, and both the consumer and producer have a reference to that object.

When you pass a variable to a function, you are creating a copy of the reference, but the new reference still points to the same object on the heap. Therefore, both the consumer and producer are modifying the same object.

Comment: Is this just for C#? Say I compiled a similar native Windows application in C++, would that be a different story?

Comment: C++ is very different. Java, Python, and JavaScript do pretty much the exact same thing.

Comment: Where did you learn this information about the heap, and referencing v.s. copying? Some college course, or... book *about* the language? I do not have a formal computer science education, and would like a push in the right direction as to where I can learn more.

Comment: @StevieV: While there are rules that govern whether a variable is created on the heap or on the stack, the .NET and C# specifications consider this an *implementation detail.*  More info [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/).

Comment: Value types (i.e. primitive types and some structs) have *value semantics* in C#.  Variables containing value types point to the value, not a reference.  Assigning a value to a variable or formal parameter *copies the value,* not the reference.  Modifying such a value in a method *leaves the original passed-in variable intact.*  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx.  cc: @StevieV

Comment: @RobertHarvey Are you a mind reader? I just opened up VS on my desktop real quick to try that out and I was going to ask, *why isn't the value modified when some other object manipulates it*? So you're talking about if you passed an *int* for example, then modified it in another object... The original value would be retained? But not for some *informal* parameter?

Comment: @StevieV: Reference types don't work that way.  If you pass a variable holding a reference type into a method parameter, and then modify the object pointed to by that parameter, the original object in the original variable is modified, because the method parameter references the same object as the original variable.    See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx

Comment: So now you know the whole scoop.

Comment: @RobertHarvey As for  the first article you posted here in the comments, I feel like Mandy Patinkin in Princess Bride whenever the guy says *implementation details*.

Comment: @StevieV, to answer your question of where I learned information such as this, most of it was learned organically (by asking questions like you), however there was also a period of my life where I decided to write my own programming language. I assure you, if you ever do that, you will quickly gain an intuitive grasp of how languages are behaving behind the scenes.